# Does Swedens UA work in team-games?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Lets say I setup a game 3v3, and I'm sweden, will I automatically get the 20% bonus from having 2 allies?

Comment: I ask because I'm going to do a 12v12 with the AI. I guess I'll just do it and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it does not. I'm in a 12v12 team-game. I've made two declaration of friendships with 2 members of team 2 (me being on team 1 of course).

As you can see from my screenshot, you only receive the bonus specifically from the DoF which does not include teammates. Unfortunately :(

[image: Sweden 12v12]

Comment: Members of the same team have a special locked-in ally status that exempts them from just about every facet of diplomacy.  So it wouldn't count towards a standard Friendship count.